# Download all files shown in a view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, view, download

I'd like an easy way for a user to be presented with a view of files in a document library and then download all of the files that are shown in that view.  I'm looking at the Virto Sharepoint Bulk File Download software, but wonder if there is a way to do this built in.

Answer (score 2):

> but wonder if there is a way to do this built in.

No there is no "standard" way to download all files filtered in list view. You can simply download **all** files, copy-pasting via webdav("Open in Explorer" in ribbon). But for download filtered You can use a ribbon extension, I don't remember it's name now.. It allowed to download all documents as *.zip archive, but we refused it because of exceptions on much amount of files. Possible it was Your "Virto Sharepoint Bulk File Download software", unfortunately I can't remember it just now..

Answer (score 1):

There is no "download all files" for a view with out-of-the-box functionality.  You can work around that via "Open in Explorer" as mentioned by others but it requires manually selecting files and that can be cumbersome if there are many files and if these files are distributed in a folder structure within a library.

I would suggest you look towards a 3rd party tool as you are doing but be sure to try them out. I know there is another product on the market that does not let you target specific libraries but is deployed at the site collection level. Do you want this for select libraries or all libraries in a site collection? This is something to consider.

Comment: At the moment, it is one particular library that spawned the desire. Basically group A needs a local copy of files 1-10, and group B needs a local copy of files 5-15. I want to present views that correspond to these file groupings and allow the members of the group to easily download just those files.  It would only happen occasionally, but seemed like a way to avoid the duplication of files in folders and make it easy to download them.  If you think of the other tool provides this kind of functionality, I would be interested in checking it out.